# Working with Non-linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra

Project Euler problem 9 asks us to find the solution to $(a + b +\sqrt {a^2+b^2}
- 1000 = 0)$ which has only one solution. The equation is non-linear and any approximation technique won't work.
$(a,b,\sqrt {a^2+b^2}\in \mathbb{N} )$

I am an undergraduate student and I am interested in applicability of some concepts that are taught after high school(linear algebra, real analysis, etc.).Can a lower O(n) be achieved.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions to that equation as written...presumably you meant to add that $a,b\in \mathbb N$?  In that case we have a Pythagorean triple and a full classification is available.

Comment: As a general matter:  Diophantine equations are usually difficult and, while specific equations admit elegant solutions, general methods are scarce.

Comment: If a problem is non-linear that really doesn't tell you much at all. Very roughly speaking 'linear' means 'easy'. Then you are asking what techniques to use on problem that are not easy. That of course depends very much on the problem at hand.

Comment: For this particular problem; isolate the square root term and square everything, then rearrange and factor to get $$2(a-1000)(b-1000)=1000^2.$$

Comment: Forgot to mention a, b ,√a^2+b^2 belong to N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want $a + b + c = 1000$, where $c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and $(a,b,c)$ is a Pythagorean triple. Recall the [general formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) for generating Pythagorean triples:
\begin{align*}
a &= m^2 - n^2\\
b &= 2 mn\\
c &= m^2 + n^2
\end{align*}
Here $m$ and $n$ are positive integers with $m>n$. Combining this with $a+b+c=1000$ and simplifying yields:
\begin{equation}
m(m+n) = 500 = 2^2 5^3
\end{equation}
A little trial and error with distributing the 2s and 5s between the $m$ and $m+n$ terms (and keeping in mind that $m>n$) soon leads to the answer...

Comment: That formula only gets primitive triples.